# Using cvxpy to solve a lasso like problem

Tags: python, cvxpy, convex-optimization

It's not entirely lasso because I add an extra constraint but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to solve a problem like the following using cvxpy

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(5000,1000)
v0 = np.random.rand(1000,1)
v = cp.Variable(v0.shape)
iota = np.ones(v0.shape)

lam = 1

objective = cp.Minimize( (A@(v-v0)).T@(A@(v-v0)) + lam * cp.abs(v).T @ iota )
constraints = [v >= 0]

prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
res = prob.solve()
```

I tried various versions of this but this is the one that most clearly shows what I'm trying to do. I get the error:

`DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically: The objective is not DCP. Its following subexpressions are not: ....`

And then an error I don't undeerstand haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CVXPY is a modeling language for convex optimization. Therefore, there is a set of rules your problem must follow to ensure your problem is convex indeed. These are what cvxpy refers to DCP: [Disciplined Convex Programming](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/dcp/index.html). As the error suggests, your objective is not DCP.

To be more precise, the problem is in the objective `(A@(v-v0)).T@(A@(v-v0))`: cvxpy don't know it is indeed convex (from program point of view, it's just few multiplications).

To ensure your problem is DCP, it's best to use [cvxpy atomic functions](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/functions/index.html).
Essentially you are modeling `x^T * x` (if `x=A@(v-v0)`), which is the squares of norm 2 of a vector. `cp.norm2` is the way to ensure cvxpy will know the problem is convex.

change the line of the objective function to:

```py
objective = cp.Minimize(cp.norm2(A @ (v - v0)) ** 2 + lam * cp.abs(v).T @ iota)
```

and it works.

(Also take a look at cvxpy example of [lasso regression](https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/machine_learning/lasso_regression.html))